# How to enroll devices in Azure AD from PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune

All the instructions I've found for enrolling devices in Azure AD require the user to manually log a machine in to Azure AD themselves to enroll.

Is there any way to enroll machines from Powershell? I'm looking at enrolling about 200 machines and not looking forward to having users login to Azure AD one by one manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey. Looks like you can use:
Set-AzureADDevice (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaddevice?view=azureadps-2.0)
or

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario you should use something called bulk enrollment.

Steps are:

1. Create configuration file called provisioning package (*.ppkg) using Windows Configuration Designer tool. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/windows-bulk-enroll#create-a-provisioning-package.
   Don't use the desktop wizard here, since bulk Azure AD deployment can only be configured via advanced configuration.
2. Deploy the *.ppkg file using PowerShell command `Add-ProvisioningPackage`. More info is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-powershell